# Use of #include in C with subfolders

Tags: c

Hello I have a simple problem in C I think. I was wondering how one would go about including headerfiles in the same parent directory as the source file, but where the source files are in a subdirectory called source and the headers in a subdirectory called "headers".

This is my first time posting a question :)

I simply tried to include using the "..." but this only seems to work with files in the same directory and doesn't check the subs. My idea was to maybe move my headers to /usr/include but then it would be very annoying to find every time.

Thanks!

Answer (score -1, accepted):

```
#include "../headers/API.h"
```

definitely used to work for me, and it really should work for you, as well.

However, it would sound as if the right thing to do was to tell your build system to include the headers directory in the header search path (`-I` on all POSIX-alike targeting compilers)

Answer (score -1):

To include header files in C, you need to use the `#include` directive with the name of the header file in quotes or angle brackets. For example:

```
#include “headers/foo.h” // for a header file in a subdirectory called headers 
#include <stdio.h> // for a standard library header file
```

If you want to include a header file that is in the same parent directory as your source file, but not in a subdirectory, you can use one of these methods:

Use a relative path from your source file to your header file. For example:

```
#include “…/bar.h” // for a header file called bar.h in the parent directory
```

Add the parent directory to your compiler’s search path using an option like `-I` or /`I` (depending on your compiler). For example:

```
gcc -I… source/main.c // for gcc on Linux
cl /I… source\main.c // for cl on Windows
```

Split your header file into two files:
one that contains declarations that are needed only by your source file (`foo_int.h`), and one that contains declarations that are needed by other files (`foo.h)`. Then include `foo_int.h` in `foo.c` and foo.h in other files. This way, you can avoid circular dependencies and reduce compilation time.

Comment: Three dots or an ellipsis symbol as in your answer definitely do not work